# How can I detect if there is any flash(or light source) showing in a video？

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Imagine If I have a flash light turned on in any frame of my camera, I want to detect it and capture it. I thought about using image segmentation by thresholding any pixel that is above 230 to 255. However, if there is any other very bright background in the frame (greater than 230), it will also go to 255. Then I have tried using background subtractor in OpenCV to get the front mask image but it still does not help much because any change in the frame other than the flash will also be set to 255. Is there any way I can capture the flash and disregard the other irreverent background.

Comment: Did you try thresholding it and then using the background subtractor on the thresholded image?

Comment: Honestly I haven't but I am not very sure how it would make the result differently?

Comment: Assuming minimal camera motion you could try computing the mean pixel value at each frame (or maybe mean of squared pixel values). Interpreting this as a time series, when the derivative is high enough then there's probably a light coming on.

Comment: It seems as though thresholding isn't working for you because some of the background is too bright and that the background subtractor didn't work because it was picking up motion besides what you want.  Doing the two in sequence would prevent the background subtractor from picking up spurious motion unless the thing that was moving was also really bright which may or may not be a corner case that you care about.